# How to determine maximum continuous current on a DC motor?

Tags: motor, current-limiting

Is there a good way to determine the maximum continous current a small DC motor can handle without breakdown?

I am working with a high school robotics team.  They are using a door lock actuator to control their gripper (this design choice is fixed given deadlines.) The actuator is very happy when run in 100ms bursts to open and close and could probably sustain may thousands of cycles.

It is less happy when held closed (stall.) It draws close to 4 amperes. In testing it fails when repeatedlu held in stall for any reasonably sustained time. Yet it does need some amount of torque between fully off and fully on to hold an object. The plan is to use the short burst to close the jaw and determine an acceptable holding current using PWM. They have a few actuators, so trial and error is one method, but is there a beter way possibly using the resistance and inductance value of the motor to determine a reasonable range for continous current?

Comment: Is it a brushed, brushless or stepper motor? what is the voltage rating for the motor? have you tried looking for a datasheet from part number?

Comment: Yes, but trial and error seems easiest. At least one of the things you would have to measure is the tension of the spring by itself

Comment: Apply a small current for a while. Measure the temperature. Increase the current, rinse and repeat. Choose the maximum current that works and doesn't overheat your motor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very useful to measure the temperature of the motor steel case, because that's the stator, and it is not touching the rotor where the windings are. So the rotor can be smoking, while the stator is still cool.

However, your motor comes with a built-in thermometer, because the temperature coefficient resistance of its copper windings is 0.39%/°C.

Therefore, connect the motor to a bench power supply and stall it. Note the current going through it, then wait for it to heat.

As copper gets hotter, its resistance increases. So you should see current decrease. When it has decreased by 39%, you know the winding temperature has increased by 100°C. So if it was 20°C at the beginning, it is now 120°C, and it is time to disconnect the motor to avoid burning it. The steel case should still be cool, but it'll be cooking inside.

Note you don't need to do this experiment, you can just calculate the hot resistance value.

You can exploit this to measure the temperature of your motor and how much power it can dissipate while stalled.

Let it cool down. Then, you can set the bench power supply to 0V, stall the motor again, and slowly increase the voltage, in small steps.

Once the voltage has settled,

- if the motor receives more heating power than it can dissipate in the air, its temperature will increase, so you will see the current decrease slowly while voltage remains constant.
- On the other hand, if the motor receives less heating than it can dissipate in the air, it will cool down, so current will increase slowly.

You are looking for a voltage setting that:

1. keeps the current stable, which means the temperature is constant, which allows you to determine the power dissipated in the air, which will be equal to the input electrical power
2. keeps the motor's resistance about equal to the value measured previously, corresponding to a temperature rise of 100°C (you can use a lower temperature rise if it begins to smell funny, but 100°C should be okay). Just divide V by I displayed by the bench power supply to get the resistance, and you know the winding temperature.

The settings on the power supply will be the maximum power your motor can dissipate while stalled. You can translate that into PWM settings, and check with the multimeter that V*I is indeed what you wanted.

If you don't get enough torque, another solution is to use a fan to blow some air into the motor when it is stalled. Not **on** the motor, but into it, through the vents, because you want to cool the windings. When it is turning, its own fan works, but not when it is stalled. That is not likely to perform any miracle, but who knows.

Comment: Bobflux, Thanks so much for the incredibly detailed response. The students got it running at .25A today! They have been working really hard all year and the final event is this weekend. Your response was a big help.